# Awwww snap! "Your BMI calculation is not correct"

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am working on a BMI calculator technical assessment but I am stuck in the stage of using formula. The instructions to compute BMI are:

> **Instruction 1:**
>
> Each user's height is expressed in feet, so the calculation needs to first convert it to meters. **HINT:** multiple height by  **0.3048**.
>
> **Instruction 2:**
>
> **BMEye** calculates BMI with an advanced algorithm! BMEye has the notion of countries with the healthiest diet and they are **Chad, Sierra Leone, Mali, Gambia, Uganda, Ghana, Senegal, Somalia, Ivory Coast, and Isreal** .
>   If the user is from any of these countries, then the calculated BMI figure is multipled by **0.82**, bringing it down a little.
>
> **Last instruction**:
>
> Following the guide and hints above, get computeBMI to use the user's weight, height, and country to calculate and return the BMI value for the user.

**What I have tried to do:**

I tried to run the code in my local editor sublime text and it calculates BMI correctly but When I bring the code on Google grade tracker which is platform running the assessment, it throws an error saying "Your BMI calculation is not correct!"

Anyone might help me to come up a fix with this error? Below is a function which receives user's Object by grabbing height, weight and country to help with the calculations.

```
const computeBMI = ({weight, height, country}) => {
           const LowBMIcountries = ["Chad", "Sierra Leone", "Mali", "Gambia", 
            "Uganda", "Ghana", "Senegal", "Somalia", "Ivory Coast", "Israel"];  
              const bmiRate = 0.82;

               let ConvertHeight = height * 0.3048;

               let BMI = weight / Math.pow(ConvertHeight,2);

                if (LowBMIcountries.includes(country)) {
                  BMI *= bmiRate;
                 }
               return Math.round(BMI, 2);

            };
```

Comment: What unit is `weight` in? Pounds or kilograms? And what is the actual formula for BMI?

Comment: @mplungjan This question is 100% fine.

Comment: Yeah I think he is missing the expected output. Can we just get the OP to add some information. Your edit is incorrect. His function accepts one object with the arguments. Your calls pass 3 parameters

Comment: Plus you have made this edits without even knowing the units in use in this calculation, we need the OP to provide more details.

Comment: @VLAZ, weight is in kilograms and height in feets to be converted in meters before calculations the formula is weight/ height^2

Comment: *"Each user's height is expressed in feet"* `height:165` these giants ;)

Comment: @Emmanuel PLEASE 1. Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56442888/edit). 2. Click the `[<>]` snippet editor. 3 Add the code EXACTLY the way you run it, with whatever change you have added like the .toFixed. Also please move the LowBMIcountries array outside the function - and spell Israel correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days, I have came up with the right answer to this challenged question, I know it would be useful for others in future.

```
const computeBMI = ({weight, height, country}) => {

const countries = ["Chad", "Sierra Leone", "Mali", "Gambia", "Uganda",              
          "Ghana", "Senegal", "Somalia", "Ivory Coast", "Isreal"];

          const hm = height * 0.3048;
          const ratio = (countries.includes(country) ? 0.82 : 1);

      const BMI = (weight / (hm * hm)) * ratio;
          return parseFloat(BMI).toFixed(1);

           };
```

Answer (score 0):

The question makes no mention of rounding not to mention your usage of `Math.round` is incorrect. Math.round accepts one argument and rounds to the nearest integer. If you want two decimal points, use `toFixed(2)`.

Comment: Good point - the instructions don't say what number to return but `Math.round` will only return whole numbers.

Comment: _When I bring the code on Google grade tracker which is platform running the assessment, it throws an error saying Your GMI calculations is not correct!._

Comment: @mplungjan that's because you made incorrect edits to the initial code posted by OP.

Comment: @mplungjan but...[the suggested change works](https://jsbin.com/xetuhesigi/edit?js,console). We just don't know what the verification looks like - it might require three significant digits. Although original code *suggests* it's 2. The question details don't specify.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, I've flagged him. He is making incorrect edits that cause run time errors without even knowing the syntax and making false accusations.  Emmanuel, If there are further problems, please let me know and I will help you.

Comment: @mplungjan you had a comment previously saying that `.toFixed` produces NaN.

Comment: I tried to use return `BMI.toFixed(2);` but the error persists , no luck

Comment: What is the expected output and what is the output that you get?

Comment: What happens when you just return `BMI`? Where does it say it needs to be rounded?

Comment: Random thought - the function might need to return a *number*, so `Number(BNI.toFixed(2))` could be the correct output. Guessing here - I don't know what the expectation is...

Comment: @AvinKavish, for `height : 6` and `weight : 68`,`country: Mali` I am getting output as `BMI: 16.67`  which true but the system is still throwing this error: **Awwww snap! Your BMI calculation is not correct. Review the instructions and continue**

Comment: Have you tried @VLAZ suggestion to convert the output back to a number, `Number(BMI.toFixed(2))` ? toFixed(2) converts to string. You also do Math.round(BMI * 100) / 100 to round to 2 decimal points without parsing a string.

Comment: So I am totally frustrated about what to do next.

Comment: This works `return Number(BMI.toFixed(2));` the same like `return BMI.toFixed(2);` and still error not fixed.

Comment: I did this before posting here.

Comment: [link] (https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/urgent-help-how-do-i-build-specname-a-simple-bmi-calculator-application-with-the-below/275659?page=3) , it is unanswered on that thread when you follow the link.

Answer (score 0):

study the below..

```
entervar computeBMI = function({weight,height,country}) {



    const bmiScale = 0.82;
    let feetToMeter = 0.3048;


     const countries = ['Chad','Sierra Leone','Mali','Gambia','Uganda',
              'Ghana','Senegal','Somalia','Ivory Coast','Isreal'];
   const heightinmeter = (height * feetToMeter);

    let bim = ((weight)/(heightinmeter ** 2));


    if(countries.includes(country)) {bim = bim * bmiScale}

    var fixednum = bim.toFixed(1);

    return fixednum;


  }
```